# How to handle >100 Messages per Second with AMQP/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

we're currently prototyping a microservice (Node v8.3.0) which have to consume about 60-150 messages per second of a RabbitMQ (RabbitMQ 3.6.12, Erlang 19.2.1). Sometimes it works like a charm and there are no remaining messages in the queue. But most of the time the messages stuck, only 5-20 messages per second get handled and and accumulate to up to 3M messages in the queue.

Now we're really curious about how to handle all those messages with a single consumer. Because there are already some Java consumer handling all those messages without any delays. We use [this node library](https://github.com/lanetix/node-lanetix-amqp-easy) based on [amqplib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node). Furthermore the handler acknowledges the incoming messages immediately — the business logic is absolutely asynchronous. So even without any business logic it stucks. The exchange's type is `topic`, it isn't `durable` and the queue has the `auto-deleting` feature enabled. We tried disabled prefetch, prefetch = `1` and `100`, without any success.

So..

1) Which AMQP/RabbitMQ library for node do you use?
2) How many messages get handled per second?
3) Any further improvements/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Without your integration code this is really hard to answer. An AMQP server like RabbitMQ can typically handle a lot more than hundreds per second, though you may need more channels and/or connections to make that happen.

Comment: https://github.com/lanetix/node-lanetix-amqp-easy#usage — the mentioned effect occurs in the shown example as well (connect + consume + console.log). 1 connection, 1 channel, 1 queue.

Comment: Try different AMQP libraries and try running more than one worker at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a Java consumer that works correctly points to either `amqplib-easy`, `amqplib` or your code as the culprit. Also, note that using a single queue in RabbitMQ is an anti-pattern as queues are the unit of concurrency in the broker.

I have put together a [test project](https://github.com/lukebakken/SO-47081053) that includes a `README` on running a Node consumer with the RabbitMQ PerfTest application (Java). You should familiarize yourself with PerfTest as it provides many features for evaluating the performance capabilities of your environment.

In my test environment, I can sustain a publish rate of `4096`msg/sec easily. If I increase that to `8192` I can see messages back up due to the fact that the Node app can't consume fast enough. It would be interesting to compare using "plain" `amqplib` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! gonna test it with "plain" `amqplib` and our business logic! will publish the results ASAP :)

Comment: tried the test setup in combination with `rabbot` — handles up to 14k messages per second on the latest macbook air. So `amqplib-easy` is not as fast as possible...next step: figure out the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for responding with what you found. The [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) is a great resource should you have further questions.

Comment: If you believe I correctly answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!